# Best practice for adding app configuration files into kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, containers, configuration-files

I have the following setup:

An **azure kubernetes cluster** with some nodes where my application (consisting of multiple pods) is running.
I'm looking for a good way to make a **project-specific configuration file** (a few hundred lines) **available for two of the deployed containers** and their replicas.

The configuration file is different between my projects but the containers are not.

I'm looking for something like a read-only file mount in the containers, but haven't found an good way. I played around with persistent volume claims but there seems to be no automatic file placement possibility apart from copying (including uri and secret managing).

Best thing would be to have a possiblility where **kubectl makes use of a yaml file** to access a specific folder on my developer machine to push my configuration file into the cluster.

- **ConfigMaps are not a proper way to do it** (because data has to be inside the yaml and my file is big and changing)
- For **volumes there seems to be no automatic way to place files inside them at creation time**.

Can anybody guide me to a good solution that matches my situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a configmap for this, but the configmap includes your config file. You can create a configmap with the content of your config file via the following:

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=my-config.ini=/path/to/your/config.ini
```

and the bind it as a volume in your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config
      mountPath: "/config"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: my-config #the name of your configmap
```

Afterwards your config is available in your pod under `/config/my-config.ini`